# how to store c# datetime in text database field

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have built a dynamic form system, that accepts types of textfields, dropdowns and datetimes.

The form answers are also dynamic, everything is stored as text, or a text version of the id to the dropdown answer.

For datetimes, I want to know what the best format to serialise a c# datetime to text is, purely to use for seralisation. I already have to and from Unix tics extension working, which I could use for this as well as my javascript calls. But I feel there is a better option.

Obviously DateTime.Parse will be used on the way back, but what to use on the way out?

Comment: Do you need only dates or also times? Do you need to execute queries on these fields or not?

Answer (score 4):

You'd just use `ToString` with an appropriate [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) date/time format string.

However, you need to be *very* careful about this:

- I'd suggest using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to perform the conversion (and likewise when parsing) to avoid culture-specific values
- You need to consider whether to also serialize the `Kind` of the `DateTime`. Are these always local, universal or unspecified `DateTime` values? Should you actually use `DateTimeOffset` and serialize the offset too?
- What precision do you need?
- What else will be reading this data? A "standard" format such ISO-8601 might be a good idea, potentially extended to maintain the same precision as `DateTime` itself. (The standard `o` or `O` format string will produce ISO-8601 strings.)

Answer (score 0):

For round-tripping DateTime values [the obvious solution is to use the "o" format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882584.aspx).

Unless you have constraints on the length of the string, and are prepared to sacrifice either precision, the Kind property (UTC or Local), or both.  In this case use a custom format string that meets your needs.